Crontab permission denied
I'm getting permission denied on crontab with any command I run and I don't know why. The crontab is configured directly by my root user.
So I edit crontab with the root user with this command:
sudo crontab -e

In the crontab I add this testing line
*/1 * * * * echo "Cron job ran" >> /var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview/cron_test.log 2>&1

where the permission of nextcloud-imagepreview are this
root@ubuntu1:/etc/cron.d# ls -ld /var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview/
drwxrwsrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun 24 17:20 /var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview/
root@ubuntu1:/etc/cron.d#

but checking the status of cron I have this
root@ubuntu1:/etc/cron.d# sudo systemctl status cron
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-06-24 17:41:26 UTC; 22min ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 27922 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9226)
     Memory: 352.0K (peak: 2.2M)
        CPU: 296ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─27922 /usr/sbin/cron -f -P

Jun 24 18:00:01 ubuntu1 CRON[32222]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:01:01 ubuntu1 cron[32370]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:01:01 ubuntu1 CRON[32370]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:02:01 ubuntu1 cron[27922]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Jun 24 18:02:01 ubuntu1 cron[32554]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:02:01 ubuntu1 CRON[32554]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:03:01 ubuntu1 cron[32701]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:03:01 ubuntu1 CRON[32701]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:04:01 ubuntu1 cron[32855]: Permission denied
Jun 24 18:04:01 ubuntu1 CRON[32855]: Permission denied

I even try to run only the echo "Cron job ran" without saving in the directory (to have a very simple command) but each minute I continue to have a permission denied.
What i can do to solve this?
I aslo try this  from another post but this didn't work
root@ubuntu1:/var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview# chown root:crontab /usr/bin/crontab
root@ubuntu1:/var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview# chmod g+s /usr/bin/crontab
root@ubuntu1:/var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview# ls -al /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 39664 Apr 10 12:39 /usr/bin/crontab
root@ubuntu1:/var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview#

(I'm on Ubuntu 24.04, on a cloud testing VM where the SSH user is already configured as a root for the access and no additional user is configured. So everything on the server is run as an user)

There's no need to use sudo when you're already root

you can post your solution as an answer below and then accept it after waiting 48 hrs. This will gain you additional reputation points.

If you have a solution for your issue, consider adding it as an answer in the answer box at the bottom of the page. You may later "accept" your own answer, marking the issue as solved.  In the meantime, I have rolled back your addition of the solution to the body of the question (it will still be part of the revision history, obviously).  I will add this solution as a "community wiki" answer if it turns out that you are ignoring it after a few days or weeks.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

This is mostly comment but space is limited.

SSH user is already configured as a root for the access and no additional user is configured. So everything on the server is run as an user

I think you are saying that the only user on the host is root. That's bad. Don't do that. Sometimes it's unavoidable to run some things as root, but these cases are rare and certainly do not require exposing the root account via ssh.

Permission denied

So permission could have been denied for:

running cron jobs as the root user - did you check /etc/cron.allow and cron.deny?
writing to the output file. Yes, you checked the filesystem permissions, but did you check the filesystem was mounted rw? Did you check if there were MAC constraints in the systemd unit for cron?
executng the command (although given the command was echo and this is the root user, that's unlikely).


I add this testing line

Is there anything else in the crontab file?
What's in the logs?
What happens if you add a cron job which does NOT attempt to write to file?

A very good checklist for cron errors. I would add that error messages that aren't captured into a specific log file (i.e. * * * * * /path/to/myscript > /tmp/myscript.log 2>&1 may be  sent to the mail account of the user/owner of the crontab and then viewable with mail.

This doesn't actually answer what seems to be the main question: "What i can do to solve this?" It only offers some possible causes for the implied question in the first sentence: "I'm getting permission denied on crontab with any command I run and I don't know why."

"This is mostly comment but space is limited." That is not a reason to post comments or requests to the OP to provide more details as an answer.

@Vilinkameni: There are many posts here on SO sites where the OP does not provide NEARLY enough information about a symptom or symptoms to provide a definitive explanation of what happened. This does not stop many commentators from posting answers to what they think the root cause issue is. This is not constructive. Sometimes the right thing to do is to close the question on the basis that there is not enough information. That usually does not help the OP. I have tried to provide a list of the next steps and some of the possible causes for the error.

Quoting the text shown when hovering over the "Add a comment" link: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." This "answer" is basically a list of questions asking for more information from the OP, which would have been better to do in a comment to the OP. I repeat, it is currently not an answer.

Have you tried putting the required command in /etc/crontab - the system-wide crontab file? Here's mine:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )

In the system-wide crontab you specify which user the command should be run as, so in your case it would be root in the 6th column. This crontab is edited just like any other text file, e.g. nano /etc/crontab since you're already root.
The crontab command edits and installs per-user crontab files, not the system-wide crontab file.

I just tried adding to /etc/contab this line:
*/1 * * * * root echo "Cron job ran" >> /var/log/nextcloud-imagepreview/cron_test.log 2>&1
then I restarted cron:
sudo systemctl restart cron
But the error is still the same:
untu1 cron[27281]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Jun 24 20:22:01 ubuntu1 cron[27335]: Permission denied
Jun 24 20:22:01 ubuntu1 CRON[27335]: Permission denied

@Neptune glad to see you've solved your issue and updated the original question
